# How do I look at the git differences from another branch, for only the currently-modified files?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Often when I'm baselining tests, I want to see what's changed in the test products relative to the merge parent, but at that time I don't want to look at all differences.  (I.e., I don't want to see code, or tests I've already worked through in earlier changesets on my branch.)

How do I narrow the diff to just the files that are currently modified?

Comment: are you checking diff against the current state of the merge parent branch or against the  point of merge?

Comment: For the sake of the question, i'm looking to get the difference from any known-good reference commit.  Often the point of the merge, but that explanation is for context, not fundamental to what I was trying to figure out in git.  Unclear to me why the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to do

```
git diff <branch> -- $(git diff --name-only)
```

This has the limitation that you have to run it in the root directory for the path to be interpreted correctly.

If you don't want that limitation you can use sed and xargs

```
git diff --name-only HEAD | sed 's/^/:\/:/' | xargs git diff <branch-or-commit> --
```

Answer (score -1):

```
git diff --name-only HEAD | xargs git diff <branch-or-commit> --
```

You must be in the root directory of the repository when you run this.

Comment: I posted the question because I found it tricky to find how to do this.  Happy to hear if there are simpler ways.

Comment: Downvote explanation?  I like the $() better than xargs, but this is not invalid as far as I can tell.